# Why there is no option to delete sms in marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

why there is no option to delete sms in marketing cloud, whereas we can delete journeys, emailers, data extensions etc. on the other hand.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a product design question, though I agree it's not very userfriendly.

Anyway, you should always mark the SMS messages that are not in use / expired as *Inactive* in MobileConnect, as this way they will at least get removed from the view in 6 months time.

So while you cannot delete them manually, the documentation states the following:

> After 180 days, MobileConnect archives inactive messages and removes
>   them from view. You can still review information on archived messages
>   in the calendar on the day the message was sent.

- [**Deactivate SMS Message**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_activating_or_inactivating_messages_in_mobileconnect.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the SMS message, which is in DRAFT status simply by selecting a different template. The popup will tell you that "changing the template will discard the draft". And eventually, the message will be deleted.